# Users table won't be created while other tables are OK

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I have this symfony application to use as reference and learning tool, and it's not written by me. Anyway to use the application I need to create the database and the tables, but when try to do so with doctrine migrations it complains that there's some syntax errors, since I didn't write the SQL code I have no idea what's wrong because it stops only at users table but other tables are created succesfully.
Here's the error message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, passw VARCHAR(255) NOT NU
>     LL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, is_blocked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf
>     8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for th
>     e right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, passw VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, is_blocke' at line 1

Here's the generated migration:

```
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE country (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE game (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, referee_id INT DEFAULT NULL, tournament_id INT NOT NULL, home_team_id INT NOT NULL, away_team_id INT NOT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL, round SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, game_nr SMALLINT NOT NULL, is_playoffs_game TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, playoffs_round SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, group_nr SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, home_score SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, away_score SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_232B318C4A087CA2 (referee_id), INDEX IDX_232B318C33D1A3E7 (tournament_id), INDEX IDX_232B318C9C4C13F6 (home_team_id), INDEX IDX_232B318C45185D02 (away_team_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE player (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, team_id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, goal_count INT NOT NULL, b_date DATETIME NOT NULL, number SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_98197A65296CD8AE (team_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE team (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, country_id INT NOT NULL, tournament_id INT DEFAULT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, venue VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, contacts VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, region VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, state SMALLINT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_C4E0A61FA76ED395 (user_id), INDEX IDX_C4E0A61FF92F3E70 (country_id), INDEX IDX_C4E0A61F33D1A3E7 (tournament_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE tournament (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, country_id INT NOT NULL, type_id INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, tournament_desc VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL, rounds SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, playoffs_places SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, rounds_per_pair SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, group_count SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, players_on_field SMALLINT NOT NULL, rules VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL, prizes VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, venue VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, contacts VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, code VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, is_started TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, is_ended TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_BD5FB8D977153098 (code), INDEX IDX_BD5FB8D9F92F3E70 (country_id), INDEX IDX_BD5FB8D9C54C8C93 (type_id), INDEX IDX_BD5FB8D9A76ED395 (user_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE tournament_type (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, passw VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, is_blocked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game ADD CONSTRAINT FK_232B318C4A087CA2 FOREIGN KEY (referee_id) REFERENCES user (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game ADD CONSTRAINT FK_232B318C33D1A3E7 FOREIGN KEY (tournament_id) REFERENCES tournament (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game ADD CONSTRAINT FK_232B318C9C4C13F6 FOREIGN KEY (home_team_id) REFERENCES team (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game ADD CONSTRAINT FK_232B318C45185D02 FOREIGN KEY (away_team_id) REFERENCES team (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE player ADD CONSTRAINT FK_98197A65296CD8AE FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE team ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C4E0A61FA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE team ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C4E0A61FF92F3E70 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE team ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C4E0A61F33D1A3E7 FOREIGN KEY (tournament_id) REFERENCES tournament (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE tournament ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BD5FB8D9F92F3E70 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE tournament ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BD5FB8D9C54C8C93 FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES tournament_type (id)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE tournament ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BD5FB8D9A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)');
```

Comment: What MariaDB version are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB

Comment: JSON data type only appeared in 10.2.7: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/

Comment: Thank you, saved me alot of trouble!